# Why are higher-order components a lot more useful than the regular component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to grasp the understanding of why higher order components are highly valued over the regular components? I read a tutorial on them and that higher order components are good because they: 1) Allow code re-use, logic and bootstrap abstraction. 2) Able to do render highjacking. 3) Able to abstract state and manipulate them. 4) Able to manipulate props. Source: [link](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e)

An example of a higher order component in code was shown there as:

```
function refsHOC(WrappedComponent) {
  return class RefsHOC extends React.Component {
    proc(wrappedComponentInstance) {
      wrappedComponentInstance.method()
    }

    render() {
      const props = Object.assign({}, this.props, {ref: this.proc.bind(this)})
      return <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
    }
  }
}
```

These look almost the same exact code as a regular class definition that receives props and you are still able to "manipulate props" and "manipulate state" inside that class

```
class Something extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { food: 'no_food_received_yet' } 
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ food: 'apple' });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <p>{ this.state.food }</p>
       <h2>{ this.props.food }</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Actually I didn't get to manipulate or mutate the props but I can just receive them, apply them to state and output that state.

This is not to bash on higher order components---this is actually the complete opposite. I need to understand where I am wrong and why I should integrate higher order components into my react app.

Answer (score 3):

HOCs *are* absolutely useful, but they're useful in the same way any "higher order" function is.

Consider the following component:

```
let Button = props => <button style={{ color: props.color }} />
```

You could make another component called BlueButton:

```
let BlueButton = props => <Button color="blue" />
```

There's nothing wrong with that, but maybe you want *any* component to be able to be blue, not just a button. Instead we can make a generic HOC that "blueifies" the passed component:

```
let blueify = Component => props => <Component {...props} style={{ color: 'blue' }} />
```

Then you can make blue buttons, blue divs, blue anything!

```
let BlueButton = blueify(Button)
let BlueDiv = blueify(props => <div {...props} />)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had an app where certain screens were private and only available to authenticated users. Imagine you had 3 such screens. Now on each screen's container component you can have the logic to check if the user is authenticated and let them through if they are, or send them back to login when they are not. This means having the exact same logic happen 3 times. With a HOC you can code that logic just once and then wrap each private screen in with the HOC thus giving you the same logic over and over, but the code only needs to exist in one place. This is an example of great code reuse that HOCs offer.

Answer (score 1):

Higher order components are more *generalized,* and so in theory can be applied to a broader number of cases.  In the more general sense, higher-order components (and higher-level languages) tend to be  *more expressive.*

In your case, the difference is readily apparent. The non-generalized (lower-order) component *has hard-coded HTML in it.*  This is programming 101; constant declarations like PI are preferred over hard-coded declarations like 3.14159 because they give meaning to magic numbers and allow one point of modification.

A simple example of a higher order "component" (in this case a higher order function) is a sort function that takes as one of its arguments an ordering function.  By allowing the ordering to be controlled by an outboard function, you can modify the behavior of the sort without modifying the sort function itself.